# How can I get my data (Pandas Dataframe) to align properly in my Flet (Python) app output?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, alignment

So I'm building a data entry app for shop floor operators (manufacturing) to use so they can log inventory tags that are entered into our main inventory system.  Users enter the requested data and the program appends the data to a CSV file.  The CSV file is connected to Excel to provide the supervisor with a real-time view of tags entered.  However, I also want to provide a view of entered tags so that the user has a list built within the app.  To do this, I'm using Pandas to re-import the CSV into the app and display the X number of tags entered.  If I print the variable with the pandas dataframe assigned, the data is nicely organized into columns and rows (with header) in my VS Code terminal.

The problem: even though the data displays in my app, the data isn't really organized (aligned) in nice even columns. Is there something I'm not doing or am doing wrong?  If needed, I can provide code...but one should be familiar with Flet.

Thank you!!

[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

visualizing a pandas dataframe usually works better with the display built-in function rather than print, but without any code it's hard to see if that would help here. Another option might be to get it created as an image first and then displayed.